# Is there a better way to get only the latest entry for each partition key + sort key prefix?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

We currently have a table that has both a partition key and sort key that make up the primary key.

They're both strings.

Example:
p_id: A#2021-04-21 (+)
s_id: XYZ#2#1634925978 (, , )

A use case of ours is to get *all* items for a given partition (regioncode+date), but ONLY the latest for a given id and code.

So for example if we had:

```
A#2021-04-21 , XYZ#2.0#10000 , <other attributes> 
A#2021-04-21 , XYZ#2.0#20000 , ...
A#2021-04-21 , QRS#2.0#10000 , ...
```

We'd only want to get

```
A#2021-04-21 , XYZ#2.0#20000 , ...
A#2021-04-21 , QRS#2.0#10000 , ...
```

To do this currently, I'm just doing:

```
        response = self.table.query(
            KeyConditionExpression=Key(self.table_key_name).eq(f"{region_id}#{date_key}")
        )
```

And then getting out the items, and having to manually make a map for each sort key prefix up until the epoch milliseconds / timestamp. Then for each key, set the value only if the timestamp is newer than whatever was previously there.

Is there a way to do this faster and utilize the query itself more? I've debated adding the pieces in the ID as attributes and maybe being able to use some kind of filtering but I don't think I see anything that would let me do the equivalent of a "group by" like I want here. Do I have no choice but to create some kind of Index?

Any ideas? Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

DDB doesn't support aggregations, MIN/MAX/COUNT/SUM/, like an RDBMS does...

One solution, is to use a "trigger", DDB Streams + Lamdba, to aggregate the needed data for you.  See [Using Global Secondary Indexes for Materialized Aggregation Queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-gsi-aggregation.html)

You might also want to consider looking at various ways to [implement versioning of your DDB data](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implementing-version-control-using-amazon-dynamodb/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the latest item, then your Sort Key should end in an ISO8601 standard format date that is determined when the item is added. You can then do a Query and because your sort key is ending in an iso8601 standard date, the first item returned is automatically the last item added. (ISO8601 date format being 'alphabetical' and Sort Keys being ... well automatically sorted'. (and if you tell it to order the response in the opposite direction, then the first item returned is automatically... the first item!)

You will need to do something like `SK: SOME_QUALIFIER#YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:SSZ00:00` - and then do your query with your SK `begins with "SOME_QUALIFIER#"`. - so you will have to think about how you want to organize this, but it is entirely possible to do taking advantage of the fact that the sort key is automatically sorted.

Alternatively, if you are only going to be doing this once in a while (ie for a generated report or someting) Its OK to put your last updated date (or last created, which ever is more important) in its own attribute (And with composoite type keys you often should anyways!!!) and then create an index with that as your sort key, and something else (either report Type or something) for your PK. Then you can query that PK and get the latest item there

MIN/MAX and many other sql style calls can be tricked by making clever use of the sort key.

Comment: That's interesting - if we want to get the first value for all "SOME_QUALIFIER"s though, would we still be able to utilize something like this? Right now we're not querying with anything in the SK because we want to get all values of SOME_QUALIFIER (just only the latest one for each SOME_QUALIFIER)

Was your suggestion more along the lines of querying for each SOME_QUALIFIER value?

Comment: you could have an inverse index, that just swaps the PK and the SK as an index. Of course if your times are very granular, this becomes an issue.

Again - if its just once every now and then kind of request then definitely just do an index with the datetime as the SK by itself (no qualifiers) . You could also use a combination of > (some day) and a filter expression to only see the ones you want of SOME_QUALIFIER - combination of this would possibly get what you want.